# FORCE closing 'rogue' threads if abort() doesn't work

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, abort, forceclose

As title implies. 
Yes, i know it's horribad to use .abort() but hear me out

I'm using 2 threads, The main thread (of my app) and a socket listen thread (familiar sound anyone?)
Instead of using asynchronous .AcceptAsync() calls (tbh, main reason is that i haven't looked too much into them), I have the thread just hang on socket.Accept(); 
Ofcourse, when i call thread.Abort(), the thread doesn't close because it's still waiting for a connection, once it passes Accept() it'll abort just fine.

Code:

```
    void listenserver()
    {
        while (run)
        {
            fConsole.WriteLine("Waiting for connections..");
            connectedsock = mainsock.Accept();
            connected = true;
            fConsole.WriteLine("Got connection from: " + connectedsock.RemoteEndPoint);
```

...
and elsewhere:

```
    private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!run)
        { //code ommitted.
        }
      else
        {
            run = false;
            listenthread.Join(3000);
            if (listenthread.IsAlive)
            {
                fConsole.WriteLine("Force-closing rogue listen thread");
                listenthread.Abort();
            }
            button_start.Text = "Start";
            groupBox_settings.Enabled = true;
        }
```

is there any way of assuring the thread will end, not being to stuff the whole thing in a seperate app and then ending that? 
Note that i DO have thread.IsBackground set to true (as suggested in other forum threads), it doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: If you know that `BeginAccept` and `EndAccept` will solve your problems, why do you go on asking for a solution that doesn't involve these methods?

Comment: Because i only want 1 connection open simultaneously. and i know working with async will expand my code massively, so i thought i'd keep it as simple as possible and do it like this. Guess this isn't a possibility, i'll just use acceptasync then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a thread, you might as well just use `BeginAccept`. Async code doesn't need to complicate your code, since you can use lambdas like this:

```
var socket = new Socket(...);

socket.BeginAccept(result =>
{
    if (this.abort)
    {
        // We should probably use a signal, but either way, this is where we abort.
        return;
    }

    socket.EndAccept(result);
    // Do your sockety stuff
}, null);
```

Even with a separate method definition for the `AsyncCallback`, the code isn't complex.

By doing async IO you're also being a lot more efficient with the CPU time, since between the call to `BeginAccept` and `EndAccept`, the thread can be reused for other processing. Since you're not using it for anything purposeful while waiting for the connection, holding up a thread is pretty meaningless and inefficient.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but you have to keep a thread looping anyway since otherwise the program would exit (since it's a console project in this case). Or does BeginAccept() block the thread too? without being uninteruptable that is..-- Anyway, i'll mark this as a good answer, besides I already found a way to kill the socket, it'll throw an interrupted exception if you close the socket in another thread, if you handle that you can close the thread gracefully.

Comment: You would have to keep the GUI thread alive, yes. `BeginAccept` will return immediately.